# Force Program to Start As Root and Drop it later

Tags: c++, linux, wxwidgets, root

I want program to start as root so that I might be able to perform update and then drop privileges. In Windows I just use manifest to fore user but I cannot find a way to do it in Linux. I have searched SO and I found a lot of questions asking how to elevate to root (which is not what I want).

A good example of app that illustrates what I need is Synaptic Package manager (in Debian OS). When you click icon to start it, it presents a dialog requiring password. then you can do whatever.

If that is not clear I need something like `gksudo myapp` so that it prompts user a password.
Whichever scheme you propose, it will be great to add on how to drop privileges to norma user so that I can start my normal app again (after update have finished)

If am not clear please point out so that I clarify

Comment: If those are open source... look at the source?

Comment: you mean Synaptic? Its a python program not a Cpp so it might be harder let a lone searching for a functionality. If there is a C/C++ app I would love to check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest idea that I can think of is to make a separate executable which does work as root user. You launch it from your GUI executable with root privileges using `gksudo` or `kdesu` and connect to it using some IPC method (pipe, unix message queue, shared memory). You update the GUI when the root process does the work. Only worker process is running as root so when it finishes the GUI app will have normal user permissions.

Example:

```
// this has to be executed in another thread because system()
// will block the GUI thread until the command finishes
int code = system("gksudo command");
if(code == 0)
    // command returned 0
else
    // non zero exit status - handle the error
```

If you are going to user input arguments to the command - never use `system()`. An attacker can do something like this `system("ls; rm -rf /")`. Better alternative would be `exec()`(do `man 3 exec`)

Comment: well I though of that and I can go for it if you can help me with an example. I will not need IPC as the two does not need to communicate at all. I need only to know that frist program (console) have terminated successfully or with error

Comment: anyway to check if gksudo is installed? I know sudo is always there

Comment: I have got similar answer which you can add to make answer even more solid. So far no other way is possible AFAICS! 
http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=38422&p=156557#p156551